# calling ls with execve

Tags: c, linux, unix

the following code should call a command with `excve` for some reason i doesn't print the contents of the current directory, but still the program returns `"ok"`

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <unistd.h>
  3 int main ()
  4 { char *argv[]={"ls",NULL};·
  5   char *env[]={"PATH=/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games",NULL};
  6   if(execve("ls",argv,env))
  7   { printf("ok\n");
  8   }
  9   else
 10   { printf("not ok\n");
 11   }
 12   return 0;
 13 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `execve` does not return on success, it's obvious that the call is failing somehow. It returns -1 on error, which would be treated as true (non-zero). That's why it's saying okay.

The most likely reason is that you haven't specified the full path to the executable, which is a requirement for `execve`. Alternatively, if you want the path to be searched, use `execvpe` instead. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec for the gory details.

Answer (score 2):

Calls to exec don't return when they succeed. You basically replace the calling program with the one you're execing to.

So if you ever run any code past the exec, it means exec failed.  I believe exec returns -1, which is why you end up printing ok.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really make much sense

```
if(execve("ls",argv,env) >0) {
    printf("ok\n");
} else {
    printf("not ok\n");
}
```

All `exec` functions do not return if they succeed, so if it returns it means it failed, you don't need to check if it returns `-1`, second issue is that the first argument to `execve()` is the file path not command name, from the man:

> execve() executes the program pointed to by **filename**.

So you just need to:

```
execve("/bin/ls", argv, env);
/* execve() only returns on error */
perror("execve");   
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

execve returns -1 on error, which evaluates as true when used in a context requiring a boolean. However, there's no point checking the return value, since if execve succeeds then it won't return.

Probably in this case, it's failing because you're not supplying the full path to 'ls'.